# Can you use Test Driven Development on UI updates?

Tags: javascript, tdd

We are starting to using Test Driven Development on a project.  We use jQuery, so I figured that QUnit would be a good TDD tool.

The drawback is, to test UI enhancement with QUnit, you would have to recreate the UI units on the test page, which doesn't seem like a real test.  One of my co-workers feels like we may be able to find a TDD tool that can test a UI without having to copy the UI elements to the test page.  Is there a good way to test UI updates/development using TDD?

Comment: FYI, this is TDD for javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I do understand the question clearly, but this may be the answer:

[FireUnit: Firebug Unit Testing for Firefox](http://fireunit.org/)